# Postgres compare text with special font/encoding

Tags: postgresql, unicode, unicode-normalization

Our users can submit some data from their phone. Some of them are using some special keyboard, allowing them to submit special text with specific font/encoding, like the one below:

The text submitted is stored as is in our Postgres database. So far so good.
However, we need to trigger certain actions based on the content sent.
In this example, comparing `fast` with  does not return true (obviously).

Is there a way to compare the two ? Thanks for the help

Comment: Would it be an option to normalize the input and store it in another column? You could have an "alphabet lookalike" translation map in the application layer, and normalize any wonky text when populating the other column. Example of an "alphabet lookalike" reference: https://github.com/codebox/homoglyph/blob/0209d35fe8ad79348b520401da8affe8df188909/raw_data/chars.txt

Comment: @tompave yes we could do that. We have a Rails API that we use to store the data submitted. But I don't see how we could map it to a real text (the content and fonts used can vary)

Comment: @lkartono There are libraries that handle *all* the unicode symbols and normalise them, tompave linked one. The number of "fonts" is limited.

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with font (how a character is rendered on the display) or encoding (which is the same for all strings in a database). Can you explain why the two strings should be considered equal? Then we would be closer to a solution.

Comment: A `text` column in the database knows nothing about fonts, it only knows ASCII values or unicode codepoints. Those two strings simply consist of different (unicode) characters. The second one happens to be displayed differently. It's essentially the same as the difference between the character A and an emoji.

Comment: What @a_horse_with_no_name said. I think that normalizing the text before persisting it would be the most solid solution. Of course it depends on how large the inputs are. How much data duplication it would cause in terms of space.